# Reference for Moments of Gamma Distribution random variable

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, gamma-distribution

I want a reference that explain the $n^{th}$ moment of the gamma random variable having shape and scale parameters for the gamma distribution, specifically the following moment equation

\begin{equation} 
E[X^n]=\theta^n \prod_{i=1}^n(k+i+1)
\end{equation}